# Why is the navigation in my WordPress ecommerce site not properly styled after removing ajax load more plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

l was using a theme that used pagination to show other pages but after a while l decided to install a plugin called ajax load more. l have been trying to revert to the original pagination style navigation by deactivating the ajax load more plugin and removing any files related to the plugin but the page does not style the navigation properly

This is the page on my website.
https://www.myhomeetal.com/product-category/audiocube/
This is the demo page
https://demo.wpthemego.com/themes/sw_revo/product-category/fashion/

l have deactivate all plugins except woocommerce which is the plugin in charge of this plugin and tried switching between the child theme and main theme.Please the client will kill me if l dont fix it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I can see an extra cart icon right after the 'Call Us' section. Try removing it.

From the theme customizer or theme options set up all the fonts properly.

```
.primary-menu .menu-title, .vertical_megamenu .menu-title {
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
}
```

This snippet is not getting renderd on your installtion